# How can I change the way content titles are generate and displayed?

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm a total amateur working on the website for my community radio station via Drupal 7. ([Here for reference](http://www.cjsf.ca/contents/vancouver-mixtape)) Each show on the station has their own content type called a Program Page, which displays, at the bottom of the page all the Program Playlists (a type of content) they have created by clicking a link on the Program Page and filling out the 'Create Program Playlist' form (http://www.cjsf.ca/node/add/station-playlist/685).

Currently these playlists are listed by an automatically-generated title that is just the date the episode aired (a field within the 'Create A Program Playlist' form), and we'd like to be able to assign custom titles to these playlists.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. I've tried editing the content type for the Program Playlist but all I have there is an un-editable 'Title' field and I can't get much further than that.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

If the title field is uneditable, that might have been done through another module or custom code (Automatic Entity Label?) that is setting the title text. I would edit the content type, and look down at the bottom and see if there are any content type settings that would be determining the title (not the "manage fields" page, but the main edit page for the content type). You might be able to re-enable editing. 
https://www.sierraclub.org/admin/structure/types/manage/station_playlist (? not sure if this link is exactly right, a guess...)

A work around would be to add a custom field that is your custom title, and then edit your view(s) to use the custom title if it exists. (The short version of how to do that would be to make the regular title hidden, and then add the new field, and use the if empty setting to populate with the text from the title.)

But figuring out how the title field is made uneditable and fixing it from there would probably be best in the long run.